# Friend function in a template class for operator<<

Tags: c++, templates, friend, ostream

What is the correct way to declare a friend function of a template class (for the std::ostream& operator<<) **in a .cpp file** ?

My current implementation does not work :

```
// MyTest.h
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class MyTest
{
    inline friend std::ostream& operator<< <T, TSIZE> (std::ostream &lhs, const MyTest<T, TSIZE> &rhs);
};

// MyTest.cpp
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> inline friend std::ostream& operator<< <T, TSIZE> (std::ostream &lhs, const MyTest<T, TSIZE> &rhs)
{
    // IMPLEMENTATION
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"...compiler errors?  Which errors?  First guess..."friend" doesn't belong in the .cpp version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To refer to `operator<< <T, TSIZE>` like you do, which is a template specialization, a declaration of the primary template must be visible. In turn `operator<<` needs a declaration of `MyTest` because it appears as a parameter.

```
// Declare MyTest because operator<< needs it
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class MyTest;

// Declare primary template
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const MyText<T, TSIZE>& rhs);

template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class MyTest
{
    // Specialization MyTest<T, TSIZE> only declares
    // specialization operator<< <T, TSIZE> as friend
    // Note that you can just use '<>' to designate the specialization,
    // template parameters are deduced from the argument list in this case
    inline friend std::ostream& operator<< <> (std::ostream &lhs, const MyTest<T, TSIZE> &rhs);
};
```

The definition you have should match those declarations. Note that since `operator<<` is a template its definition should in all likeliness be in the header.

An alternative that requires less work when it comes to writing all those preemptive declarations is for `MyTest<T, TSIZE>` to declare the whole template as a friend, not just the specialization that takes `MyTest<T, TSIZE>`.

```
// in MyTest definition
template<typename U, unsigned USIZE>
inline friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const MyTest<U, USIZE>& rhs);
```

The definition you have should also match such a declaration (the name of the template parameters has no bearing on matching declarations and definition).

For the sake of completeness, I will mention that when it comes to the friend of a class template an alternative is to define it in the class template definition. This defines a non-template friend function that is unique for each specialization.

```
// in MyTest definition
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, MyTest const& rhs)
{ /* implementation */ }
```

It is impossible to refer to such functions (e.g. `&ns::operator<<` doesn't work, unlike the other options) and they are only found via ADL.

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what the original post wanted. I will assume that it wanted the following:

```
// Some template class.
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class MyTest { };

// Some template function.
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &lhs, const MyTest<T, TSIZE> &rhs)
{
    // IMPLEMENTATION
}
```

Now it is necessary to declare this template function as friend of the class because this function needs access to protected objects of `My test`. This can be achieved with the following  definition:

```
template<class T, unsigned int TSIZE> class MyTest
{
    template<class T1, unsigned int TSIZE1> 
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &lhs, const MyTest<T1, TSIZE1> &rhs);
};
```

Template header is needed in front of the `friend` declaration because this is an unrelated template function, that does not belong to the current template class.